# BigQuery: Get a List of Dates for current month until current date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to display a list with the days in Date Format until starting from the first day of the month until the current day of the month.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution myself: I leave it here:

```sql
#StandardSQL
SELECT Date
FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS Date
```